# Sampling from interpolated data layer

Tags: qgis, data, interpolation

Im working with QGIS 1.8.0 and wanted to ask you how can I assign to each of the small squares of the map (I have the coordinates of the center each of them) values from an interpolated data layer as the one shown below? I tried to use the point sampling tool, but I can not save the interpolated data layer (at least not with the right mouse click option) so it doesn't appear in the "Layers with fields/bands to get values from" text box.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

[image: map and interpolated data]

Comment: What's the data source of the interpolated raster?

Comment: Well I had an .xls file from a weather station, converted to .csv, uploaded to QGIS and did the interpolation there, is that what you mean?

Comment: I'm trying to imagine why the raster layer would not show up int the point sampling tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is with the GRASS plugin. After importing both the vector grid (as polygons) and the raster data into GRASS, then run the module "v.rast.stats". It will give you a set of univariate statistics as additional attributes for each of the vector polygon squares. The statistics include the minimum, maximum, mean, etc. of all raster values within each vector square.

HTH